Finding the distribution of the median of three independent random variables
Problem:
Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ be independent and uniformly distributed over the
interval $(0,1)$. Let $Y_0$ be the median of the three variables. Find the  probability density for $Y_0$.
Answer:
Let $a$ be a real number on the interval $[0,1]$.
\begin{align}
P ( Y_0 \leq a ) &= { 3 \choose 2 } P( Y_1 \leq a ) \\
{ 3 \choose 2 } &= \dfrac{ 3 } { 1 } = 3 \\
P( Y_1 \leq a ) &= a \\
P ( Y_0 \leq a ) &= 3a
\end{align}
Hence the distrubtion  for for $Y_0$ is:
$$ F(u_0) = 3u_0  $$
This is wrong. I believe the first equation is wrong. I am hoping that somebody here can help.
Here is an updated solution which I believe is correct. Is it?
Let $a$ be a real number on the interval $[0,1]$.
\begin{align*}
P ( Y_0 \leq a ) &= 3P(Y_1 \leq a)^2 P(Y_1 \geq a)+P(Y_1 \leq a)^3 \\
P( Y_1 \leq a ) &= a \\
P(Y_1 \geq a ) &= 1 - a \\
P ( Y_0 \leq a ) &= 3a^2 ( 1 - a ) + a^3  = 3a^2 - 3a^3 + a^3 \\
P ( Y_0 \leq a ) &= 3a^2  - 2a^3 \\
\end{align*}
Hence the distribution  for for $Y_0$ is:
$$ F(u_0) =3u_0^2 - 2u_0^3  $$
I want to check my solution. Let me call $p_1$ be that $Y_0$ is on the interval $[0.4,06]$. A Python program that I  wrote estimates the value of $p_1$ to be
about $0.29$. Let see what my distribution
function  says:
\begin{align*}
p_1 &= F(.6) - F(.4) \\
F(.6) &= 3(.6)^2 - 2(.6)^3 = 3(.36) - 1.2(.6)(.6) \\
F(.6) &= 1.08 - 1.2(0.36) = 1.08 - 0.432 \\
F(.6) &= 0.648 \\
F(.4) &= 3(.4)^2 - 2(.4)^3 = 3(.16) - 0.8(0.4)(0.4) \\
F(.4) &= 0.48 - 0.8(.16) \\
p_1 &= 0.648 - ( 0.48 - 0.8(.16) ) \\
p_1 \doteq&  0.2960
\end{align*}
Hence, I have faith in my solution.
Is  it right now?

You got the correct CDF, but according to your problem statement, the question asks for the density, which I provided in my answer.

Your belief is justified. The event whereby the median is less than or equal to $a$ is the union of 4 disjoint events according to whether some of the variables are less than or greater than $a.$
In 3 of those 4 disjoint events, exactly one of the 3 variables $Y_1,$ $Y_2$ or $Y_3$ is greater than $a$ and the other two are less than or equal to $a.$ In the fourth event, all 3 variables are less than or equal to $a.$
Because of independence, the probability of the union of those 4 events is
$$3P(Y_1\leq a)^2P(Y_1>a)+P(Y_1\leq a)^3$$

Is my solution now correct?

Your statements are correct, but the original problem was to find the density, i.e., the derivative of $F.$

It's worth noting that the median of the sample $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)$ is also the second order statistic $Y_{(2)}$.  The formula for the density of the $k^{\rm th}$ order statistic is
$$f_{Y_{(k)}}(y) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} f_Y(y) (F_Y(y))^{k-1} (1 - F_Y(y))^{n-k}, \tag{1}$$
where $f_Y$ and $F_Y$ are the PDF and CDF of the distribution from which the $Y_i$ are drawn.  In your case, $n = 3$, $k = 2$, and for uniformly distributed $Y_i$, formula $(1)$ reduces to
$$f_{Y_{(2)}}(y) = \frac{3!}{1! 1!} y^{2-1} (1-y)^{3-2} = 6y(1-y), \quad y \in [0,1]. \tag{2}$$
